# Convert Open Api specification to postman collection programmatically

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, postman, openapi

I am typing to convert open Api specification to postman collection I have tried using node module

`openapi-to-postmanv2`

but its creating URLs in list  like

`path":["student", ":studentId"]`

what I want URLs like.

`"raw": "{{baseUrl}}/student/:studentId"`

If any other approach of conversion in different language

Comment: Can you post a sample input OpenAPI file so that others can reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to manually convert your open Api specifications because postman already supports them.

1. go to postman and click import
2. choose your open api file
3. you will have all your apis ready to be used and tested on the APIs tab !

source and more details : [Postman Supports OpenAPI 3.0](https://blog.postman.com/postman-supports-openapi-3-0/)

EDIT :

If you have to do it programmatically you can try postman's collection sdk [Collection SDK](https://learning.postman.com/docs/developer/collection-sdk/)

- Load the OpenAPI specification file into your Node.js application
- Create a new Postman collection
- Map the OpenAPI paths and operations to Postman requests and add them to the collection
- Write the Postman collection to a file

this way you have the file in the format you want, and you can do whatever post or pre processing you need.

Comment: I want to covert programmatically without using postman.

Comment: @AniketThorat you can try using postman's collection sdk in that case https://learning.postman.com/docs/developer/collection-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to do anything. When you will create a collection in the Postman, Postman runner will automatically interpret
`path":["student", ":studentId"]` as `"{{baseUrl}}/student/:studentId"`

Or probably you can explain what exactly you're trying to acheive with the raw URL? How will it help you?

I'm converting the OpenAPI to Postman using `openapi-to-postmanv2` npm package and later I make an API call to create/update/delete the collection by hitting Postman API and it is working out of the box.